# Split 4 digit numbers

Tags: php, split

I want to split a 4 digit number with 4 digit decimal .
**Inputs:**

```
Input 1 : 5546.263 
Input 2 : 03739.712  /*(some time may have one zero at first)*/
```

**Result:** (array)

```
Result of input 1 :  0 => 55 , 1 => 46.263
Result of input 2 :  0 => 37 , 1 => 39.712
```

P.S : Inputs is GPS data and always have 4 digit as number / 3 digit as decimal and some time have zero at first .

Comment: Could you provide examples of longer digits?

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: @CIA based on tag I'm assuming php

Comment: @Duniyadnd , Thanks , inputs is GPS data and just is 4 digit as number or have a zero at first .

Comment: Have you tried anything on your own? Show your code.

Comment: @Pitchinnate yes but have problem on zero digits too .

Comment: I don't get it. Are your inputs strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the following function:

```
function splitNum($num) {
    $num = ltrim($num, '0');
    $part1 = substr($num, 0, 2);
    $part2 = substr($num, 2);
    return array($part1, $part2);
}
```

Test case 1:

```
print_r( splitNum('5546.263') );
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 55
    [1] => 46.263
)
```

Test case 2:

```
print_r( splitNum('03739.712') );
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 37
    [1] => 39.712
)
```

[**Demo!**](https://eval.in/55436)

Comment: @root: Updated the answer with the output and demo :)

Comment: Thanks Amal Murali , on last edit displaced result fix , it's Ok and I Accept it .

Comment: @root: I'm not sure I understand? *on last edit displaced result fix* -- what do you mean?

Comment: first time , function return values with wrong position , `0=>46.263` and `1=>55` . Accepted ! :)

Comment: @root: Yeah, it was a silly mistake and has been corrected. Glad to have been of help :)

Answer (score 1):

`^0*([0-9]{2})([0-9\.]+)` should work just fine and do what you want:

```
$input = '03739.712';

if (preg_match('/^0*([0-9]{2})([0-9\.]+)/', $input, $matches)) {
    $result = array((int)$matches[1], (float)$matches[2]);
}

var_dump($result); //array(2) { [0]=> int(37) [1]=> float(39.712) }
```

**Regex autopsy:**

- `^` - the string MUST start here
- `0*` - the character '0' repeated 0 or more times
- `([0-9]{2})` - a capturing group matching a digit between 0 and 9 repeated exactly 2 times
- `([0-9\.]+)` - a capturing group matching a digit between 0 and 9 OR a period repeated 1 or more times

Optionally you can add `$` to the end to specify that "the string MUST end here"

***Note**: Since we cast to an `int` in the first match, you can omit the `0*` part, but if you plan NOT to cast it, then leave it in.*